# PrestaShop page is not redirecting properly

Tags: redirect, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to install PrestaShop and every time it reaches 98%, nothing happens until it tells me ***The page isn't redirecting properly***

Here's a screenshot of it:

[image]

and after a few second I have this:

[image]

I've cleared all Cookies, my browser does allow them also, I've cleared my cache and history but still doesn't work.  Note I'm using PrestaShop 1.7.0.4

Answer (score 1):

I finally succeeded in installing PrestaShop after a lot of troubleshooting. I probably won't use it anyway as this experience proved that I cannot rely on this being stable.

Through a lot of tricks, I finally figured out that I had to:

> 1st, Install from the command line with php index_cli.php (after
>   unzip'i ng both zips). the arguments need to be quoted, like
>   --db_user='user'
>
> 2nd, Install php5-gd & php5-curl then restart apache (silent error,
>   undocumented requirement!)
>
> 3rd, Allow HTTP (my server is HTTPS only but PrestaShop is too dumb to
>   realize it and keeps redirecting to the insecure pages before you set
>   this up in the admin console).

All in all, a very bad experience. if something ever breaks, good luck with troubleshooting. I would not rely on this app for income generating activities.